# Rich Text Editor for iOS without using UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, rich-text-editor

I'm doing something with rich text editor for iOS now. First I use html5 and webView to reach the goal. But finally I find it seems not work very well. Is there some way to use the UIKit or some of Apple's APIs instead of the html5 and javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You will either have to:

A) Drop support for less than iOS 6 and use the new attributed string support that is present in UITextView.

or B) Make your own custom view using CoreText, UITextInput, etc

Answer (score -1):

look at https://github.com/gfthr/FastTextView which is more good open source editor than Omni editor

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**